# Is it bad to have nested click handlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Someone mentioned this to me once but I've never found any documentation to support the claim.  Is it bad to have nested click handlers in an application?  For example:

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    //*Do things*
    $("p").on("click", function(){
        //*Do things*
    })
})
```

If it is bad practice, why, and what would be a better solution?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by nesting them that you couldn't do with them side by side?

Comment: every time you click on `div`; one more click handler gets added to `p` tag.

Comment: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/click-through-series-of-images#14737000006597157 see here

Comment: @EricPhillips, Well, with my current task, I have to click on a map object and find if I clicked on a particular thing.  If I did, then I have to click on another area in the map object to move it and update the position on the map.  I hope that made sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's generally bad, unless that's exactly what you want ?

If someone clicks a div twice, the event handler for the paragraph is attached twice, doing "things" two times, try it

```js
$('div').on('click', function() {
  $('p').on('click', function() {
    alert('This is annoyning');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>click me a few times ?</div>
<br /><br /><br />
<p>... then click me</p>
```

---

A better solution would just be to not nest the event handlers

```
var isClicked = false;

$('div').on('click', function() {
    isClicked = true;
});

$('p').on('click', function() {
    if (isClicked) // do stuff
});
```

*(simplified to show the concept, don't use global variables, jQuery has `data()`)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is bad practice. The reason is multiple clicks on the div results in you have multiple events added to the other element. Double click on the outside and you will have two clicks events added to the paragraph tag.

If you really want to have the clicks added like that you need to unbind any event already added.

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    //*Do things*
    $("p").off("click.myNameSpace").on("click.myNameSpace", function(){
        //*Do things*
    })
});
```

Other option is to add events and put logic inside the click to see if it is supposed to run.

```
(function () {
   var isActive = false;
    $("div").on("click", function(){
        isActive = false;
    });

    $("p").on("click", function(){
        if (isActive) {
            isActive = false;
            console.info("The p was clicked");
        }
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

"Is it bad practice?" : Yes, because memory allocation will happen conditionally, which is always considered to be bad due to GC churn. It also promotes a faulty logic, which relies more and more on the ability of the language to understand you as opposed to you understanding the language.

"What would be a better solution?" : Register event handlers that are necessary, apply logic within the handler to execute based on conditional variables, which are set by the other handler(s)

I.E.: Handler b is conditionally set when Event a happens. Instead: Handler a is set containing code that sets a variable referenced within Handler b. Handler b is also set. Event b fires but executes conditionally based on the referenced variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad because in your example, everytime you click "div" you'll be adding a new handler to "p".  Click three "divs" before you click a "p" and the "p" event handler will run three times.

One way to get around this is to use a delegate:

`$(document).delegate("p", "click", function () { /* do stuff */ });`

Another way is to unbind existing handlers then rebind them:

`$("p").off(); 
 $("p").on("click", function () { });`

A third way is to use dirty flags (which will need to be set as globals which isn't exactly a best practice) to check and see if a handler is already working on that event call:

`$("p").on("click", function () {
    if (flag) {
      return;
    } else {
      flag = true;
      doStuff();
      flag = false;
    }
 });`